# radgrid delay loading of a single column

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, telerik

I have a Telerik Radgrid with two different data bases, the first data source loads most of the information while the second data base loads a single column.
My problem is that the 1st data loads fast while the second one (the single column) is slow, so I'm trying to figure out a way to delay the loading of the second data source without having to wait for the whole data to be bound.
here's my code so far

ASPX:

```
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="rgPointage" runat="server" CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True" OnItemDataBound="rgPointage_ItemDataBound">


    <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="Matricule">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter Matricule column" DataField="Matricule" HeaderText="Matricule" UniqueName="Matricule">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Direction" FilterControlAltText="Filter Direction column" HeaderText="Direction" UniqueName="Direction" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" FilterControlWidth="80px">
                <ColumnValidationSettings>
                    <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
                </ColumnValidationSettings>
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter Nom column" DataField="Nom" HeaderText="Nom" UniqueName="Nom">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter Prenom column" DataField="Prenom" HeaderText="Prenom" UniqueName="Prenom">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter Etat column" DataField="motif" HeaderText="Etat" UniqueName="Etat">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter Pnt1 column" HeaderText="Pointage 1" UniqueName="Pnt1" DataField="Pnt1" DataFormatString="{0:HH:mm}">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn Display="false" FilterControlAltText="Filter src1 column" HeaderText="Source 1" UniqueName="src1" DataField="PntSource1">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter Pnt2 column" HeaderText="Pointage 2" UniqueName="Pnt2" DataField="Pnt2" DataFormatString="{0:HH:mm}">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn Display="false" FilterControlAltText="Filter src2 column" HeaderText="Source 2" UniqueName="src2" DataField="PntSource2">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter Pnt3 column" HeaderText="Pointage 3" UniqueName="Pnt3" DataField="Pnt3" DataFormatString="{0:HH:mm}">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn Display="false" FilterControlAltText="Filter src3 column" HeaderText="Source 3" UniqueName="src3" DataField="PntSource3">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter Pnt4 column" HeaderText="Pointage 4" UniqueName="Pnt4" DataField="Pnt4" DataFormatString="{0:HH:mm}">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn Display="false" FilterControlAltText="Filter src4 column" HeaderText="Source 4" UniqueName="src4" DataField="PntSource4">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter Pnt5 column" HeaderText="Pointage 5" UniqueName="Pnt5" DataField="Pnt5" DataFormatString="{0:HH:mm}">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn Display="false" FilterControlAltText="Filter src5 column" HeaderText="Source 5" UniqueName="src5" DataField="PntSource5">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter Pnt6 column" HeaderText="Pointage 6" UniqueName="Pnt6" DataField="Pnt6" DataFormatString="{0:HH:mm}">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn Display="false" FilterControlAltText="Filter src6 column" HeaderText="Source 6" UniqueName="src6" DataField="PntSource6">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

C#:

```
protected void getPointage(DateTime date)
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                if (!SP)
                    dt = getChildren(getFather());
                else
                    dt = getAll();

                if (dt == null)
                    return;
                listePointage.Clear();
                foreach (DataRow emp in dt.Rows)
                {

                    using (var DB = new PRHEntities())
                    {
                        string matr = emp["Matricule"].ToString();
                        string nomEmp = emp["NomEmploye"].ToString();
                        string prenomEmp = emp["PrenomEmploye"].ToString();
                        string direction = emp["Direction"].ToString();
                        PointagePersonne pointage = (from p in DB.Fn_PointageParJour(matr, date)
                                                     select new PointagePersonne
                                                     {
                                                         Matricule = matr,
                                                         Nom = nomEmp,
                                                         Prenom = prenomEmp,
                                                         Direction = direction,
                                                         Pnt1 = p.Pnt1,
                                                         Pnt2 = p.Pnt2,
                                                         Pnt3 = p.Pnt3,
                                                         Pnt4 = p.Pnt4,
                                                         Pnt5 = p.Pnt5,
                                                         Pnt6 = p.Pnt6,
                                                         PntSource1 = p.PntID1,
                                                         PntSource2 = p.PntID2,
                                                         PntSource3 = p.PntID3,
                                                         PntSource4 = p.PntID4,
                                                         PntSource5 = p.PntID5,
                                                         PntSource6 = p.PntID6
                                                     }).FirstOrDefault<PointagePersonne>();

                        if (!object.Equals(pointage, null))
                        {
                            pointage.PntSource1 = getSourcePointage(pointage.PntSource1);
                            pointage.PntSource2 = getSourcePointage(pointage.PntSource2);
                            pointage.PntSource3 = getSourcePointage(pointage.PntSource3);
                            pointage.PntSource4 = getSourcePointage(pointage.PntSource4);
                            pointage.PntSource5 = getSourcePointage(pointage.PntSource5);
                            pointage.PntSource6 = getSourcePointage(pointage.PntSource6);
                            pointage.motif = getmotifAbsence(matr, date);
                            listePointage.Add(pointage);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var nonPnt = new PointagePersonne()
                            {
                                Matricule = matr,
                                Nom = nomEmp,
                                Prenom = prenomEmp,
                                Direction = direction,
                                Pnt1 = null,
                                Pnt2 = null,
                                Pnt3 = null,
                                Pnt4 = null,
                                Pnt5 = null,
                                Pnt6 = null,
                                motif = getmotifAbsence(matr, date)
                            };
                            listePointage.Add(nonPnt);
                        }
                    }
                }

                rgPointage.DataSource = listePointage;
                rgPointage.DataBind();


                ViewState["pointage"] = listePointage;
                if (rgPointage.Items.Count > 1)
                {
                    btExportPointage.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                    btExportPointage.Visible = false;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
//
            }


        }
```

So what I'm trying to do is to load the method getmotifAbsence(matr, date) for each line after the radgrid is loaded and shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can. Server code is syncronous, so it goes one line at a time so it will wait for the call to return the data. If retrieval is slow, consider ways to make it faster or only bind this data on demand (e.g., add a button or a checkbox for your user to set Visible=true for the column and raise a flag so the data will be retrieved). Use AJAX so your user will have a loading indicator